# Facebook Login - how to change color scheme

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there an option to change the basic color of the Facebook Login button to be lighter and fit on darker backgrounds, I am referring to the Loging button, not the LIKE button.

This one doesn't work:

```
data-colorscheme="dark"
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may use your own customized button if that doesn't match up with your site's theme. You just need `onclick = FB.Login()`

Comment: The dark theme for login isn't available